# React Website is Blank after Deploying using Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, vite

I am trying to deploy this website using github pages. After deploying, the link shows a blank page. In the console error page I am getting the error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () [https://ammaarkhan.github.io/src/main.jsx"](https://ammaarkhan.github.io/src/main.jsx%22).

I found one solution online which was to change the "private" property to false in the package.json file which I did, and deployed again but didn't fix it. I also tried changing the homepage to ".", didn't fix it. The local host shows the website just fine. I am using vite so I followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XhoWXhyuW_I.

The repo link: https://github.com/ammaarkhan/Personal-Website
Web link: https://ammaarkhan.github.io/Personal-Website/

This is package.json file:

```
{
  "homepage": "https://ammaarkhan.github.io/personal-website",
  "name": "personal-website",
  "private": false,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emailjs/browser": "^3.11.0",
    "@react-three/drei": "^9.66.1",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^8.13.0",
    "framer-motion": "^10.12.7",
    "maath": "^0.5.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-parallax-tilt": "^1.7.145",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.11.0",
    "react-vertical-timeline-component": "^3.6.0",
    "three": "^0.152.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
    "gh-pages": "^5.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.23",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "vite": "^4.3.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are not serving the `dist` directory. From what I know, you need to have a dedicated branch for GitHub pages, build the project, and push the project along with the `dist` directory to that branch (these steps can be done within a GitHub actions workflow). And configure GitHub pages to deploy from that dedicated branch.